# When should I have to use 'set names utf8'

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I can have access to two MYSQL servers on different PCs and do the below experiment .

Run the following sql to create database and table and insert a chinese record.

```
drop database IF EXISTS test;
create database test charset utf8;
use test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('中文');
```

Execute the following PHP code to query the record.

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli('192.168.1.100', 'root', '', 'test');// Server A
$mysql->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$p = $mysql->query("select * from test");
var_dump($p->fetch_all(1));


$mysql = new mysqli('192.168.1.101', 'root', '', 'test');// Server B
$mysql->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$p = $mysql->query("select * from test");
var_dump($p->fetch_all(1));
```

The result is :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "ä¸­æ–‡"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "中文"
  }
}
```

Obviously the result from server A is in a weird format.

If I comment the code `$mysql->query("SET NAMES utf8");` on Server A , the result is correct.

If I comment the code `$mysql->query("SET NAMES utf8");` on Server B , the result is incorrect.

So `set names utf8` is a key point. I don't know the different bewteen the two MYSQL servers.

But I want to know when should I have to use 'set names utf8' ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should set the charset UTF-8 on the PHP/HTML headers, the MySQL connection object and on the tables itself. A query of `SET NAMES utf8` can be redundant.

Comment: `ä¸­æ–‡` is Mojibake for `中文` -- Somewhere there is a "latin1" that you need to get rid of.

Comment: If you are focusing on Chinese, use `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.  There are a few 4-byte Chinese characters that are not in MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  (This is irrelevant for the Question at hand.)

Comment: @Qirel As you can see on my post, the database and table itselft are created by the same sql script, and execute the same query through the same PHP script. So I don't know what let to this different result.

Comment: @RickJames I tested with the same create database and table script with utf8 setting and the same PHP query script. But one gets Mojibake result. So what may causes this result ?

Comment: I finally know the reason. Althought the create database and table script is the same, but the charset of client which execute this sql script is different. One is utf8 and another is latin1,  that is ignored by me. Thanks all. The link referred is very helpful.